# JQuery selectmenu() is not working

Tags: jquery

I've built a simple jsFiddle with jQuery UI [.selectmenu()](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)

It does not seem to work. Is there anything that I missed?

```
<select name="filter" id="id_filter_log">
    <option value="" selected>-- Select Log Status --</option>
    <option value="logged">Logged Visit</option>
    <option value="login">Logged In</option>
    <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
    <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_filter_log").selectmenu();
});
```

[View in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7797P/)

Comment: 1) as you were asked to, post your code in the question. 2) do not use onload in the fiddle when you have document.ready

Comment: @mplungjan : thx. I'll make sure never leave blank in my next post. It still not working even not using onload?

Comment: Use a newer version of jquery UI. Avril (jsFiddle example below) uses version 1.11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

html

```
<select name="filter" id="id_filter_log">
    <option value="" selected>-- Select Log Status --</option>
    <option value="logged">Logged Visit</option>
    <option value="login">Logged In</option>
    <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
    <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_filter_log").selectmenu();
});
```

[view in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7797P/5/)

Comment: Why not make that work with the JSFiddle options? What was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are importing jQuery-UI css from 1.10 or earlier. Selectmenu was added in UI 1.11 and using a different-version css is not supported, and will likely not have styles like `.ui-selectmenu-open`, hence the glitching and not closing.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it has to do with css. We should try to target specific css that causes it not to close.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the three integral css selectors which will allow this to work again.

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.ui-selectmenu-open {
    display: block;
}
.ui-selectmenu-button {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```